# Google Script - What is the name of this dialog panel?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I am working on University project that would benefit from google forms automatization. I am struggling to find any information how to code that side dialog (marked in blue circle) in Google Forms editor. I would be thankful for linking with any documentation/tutorial how to model that side dialog.

[image]

Comment: See [tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info) for more details.

Comment: it's  a sidebar probably from a addon

Answer (score 2):

The dialog is created using Google Apps Script to extend Google Forms. You can read about G-Suite Add-ons [here](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/overview) and specifically about Forms Add-ons [here](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/editors/forms). I believe the specific Add-on in your screenshot is [this](https://gsuite.google.com/marketplace/app/form_notifications/573009629797).